# How to use kexec to do a live upgrade of hotswap ram on a CentOS vm image?

Tags: centos, virtualization, memory

Just as the question states, is there a way and what's the best method todo a live ram upgrade with kexec?

Comment: What do you mean by "upgrade"? Are you talking about memory hotplug Linux technology?

Comment: What hypervisor are you using ?

Comment: @Lawrence Two separate environments here, First one is vSphere and the other is qemu-kvm.

Comment: @Greshnik hotplug is not universal nor completed at this point in time. Therefore it is not an option to support in the environment I'm working with.